# Connection refused error in jenkins for Publish coverage to GitHub plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

We want to post code coverage status comment to GitHub pull request. We configured our jenkins job with "Publish coverage to gitHub" plugin. But our build got failed with error ERROR: Step ‘Publish coverage to GitHub’ aborted due to exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:602)
Caused: org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://api.github.com/rate_limit
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:633)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:594)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:272)
at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:234)
at org.kohsuke.github.GitHub.getRateLimit(GitHub.java:318)
at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.GitHubPullRequestRepository.getGitHubRepository(GitHubPullRequestRepository.java:42)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Error while accessing rate limit API
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.GitHubPullRequestRepository.getGitHubRepository(GitHubPullRequestRepository.java:48)
    at com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.CompareCoverageAction.perform(CompareCoverageAction.java:137)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error seems to be:

```
Error while accessing rate limit API at
   com.github.terma.jenkins.githubprcoveragestatus.GitHubPullRequestRepository.getGitHubRepository
```

That looks similar to [jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/204](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/204#issuecomment-144119042)

> I've found the reason for the problem, it appears I misconfigured the secret key. After fixing that and waiting for the next period of rate limiting it works as expected.
>
> Although I solved my problem, ideally the plugin would stop sending API requests when either the rate limit or unauthorised status code is received with the appropriate log messaging.